# How to use 'this' in static method - PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, static

How can I use 'this' in a static method? I keep getting the error: `PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class could not be converted to string`

Here is the method I am trying to use:

```
public static function getFirst(){
    $this->_id = 1;
    $this->_name = $this->_db->query("SELECT name FORM users WHERE id = 1");
    $this->_occupation = $this->_db->query("SELECT occupation FORM users WHERE id = 1");
    $this->_email = $this->_db->query("SELECT email FORM users WHERE id = 1");
}
```

I need to have this method allocate all these variables in the class when I call this method on the main page:

```
$currentUser = User::getFirst();
```

So it pulls the info from the database and puts it in those variables in the class.

I am new to PHP and especially PDO, so please help me out here!
Thanks in advance

Comment: `self::$_id`... Your error is not because of this though, it's because `query()` doesn't return a string.

Comment: The magic keyword $this is reserved for context where an instance of a class type exists. In a static context such instance does not and, thus, $this cannot be used inside static method. To refer to static properties inside a static function member you can use the keyword 'self'

Comment: Or, if you need to call these things from the instance of the class, you can do inside the method `$_this = new self; $_this->_id = 1`

Comment: Query won't return "anything". So far, only one person has addressed this, in an "answer". Can you guess which one?

Answer (score 3):

You have to target it with:

```
self::$variable
```

or

```
self::function();
```

**EDIT:**

You have error in your queries...change FORM to FROM :)

Comment: This gives me this error: `HP Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: User::$_db`

Answer (score 0):

You can read here on [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

> Static methods are callable without an instance of the object created,
>   the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared
>   as static.

Answer (score 0):

$this is not available in static methods. To simplify the reasoning, think of static methods as glorified global functions. You cannot use $this inside of a global function for the same reasons, $this refers to a `class instance` and the function does not contain an instance of anything, without passing it in as a parameter, same as static methods.

You can, in all sanity, move your static methods to simpler 'functions' and the confusion will be gone.

PHP does expose a similar resolution keyword: self. self can be used inside of static methods (hear class methods, not instance methods) to refer to other `class methods` or `class attributes`. Basically: If it's static it can only reference other static methods/ attributes. If it's an instance is can reference both static and local properties via `$this` or `self`.

My real suggestion is to avoid static methods. You don't need them, use functions instead. They're usually easier to test and navigate. Otherwise use them wisely: factories being a wise and acceptable choice, which seems like what you're trying to achieve (the DB needs to be injected as a parameter as it too is not a class attribute but an instance attribute):

```
public static function getFirst($db){
    $inst = new NameOfThisClass();
    $inst->_id = 1;
    $inst->_name = $db->query("...");
    return $inst;
}
```

Comment: I cannot inject the DB as a parameter, I just need to be able to get results from the database using a static method